# How to prevent an Alarm from being destroyed even if the app is killed?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I read stuff about alarm manager on android studio and it seems to have a problem if the user intends to kill the app by means of swiping it on their respective task manager and also it is being destroyed if the phone is been rebooted. how am i going to retain the alarm then even if the app is destroyed? is there any other way how am i able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend phasing out AlarmManager for JobScheduler, which has the ability to set it as a persistant alarm across reboots.  It you're stuck supporting a version of Android without JobScheduler, you have to do it yourself by adding a BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver and rescheduling the alarm on reboot.